# some builtin css for angular material mat-table not applying

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I'm trying angular material mat-table.Data's are loading .but for table header and body some css are not applying.

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" mat-sort>  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.username}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lastName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="createddate">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Added Date </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.createdDate}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

      </table>

      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included a predefined (or custom) theme? Check the documentation on [theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme) on how to include a theme.

Comment: Yeah I have added.

Comment: Its solved.I have to import MatSortModule in module.ts file.imported it and its fixed